# Will RivetsJS cause memory leaks without calls to unbind

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, rivets.js, javascript-databinding

From the Rivets.js [documentation](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#usage-binding)

> Every call to `rivets.bind` returns a fully data-bound view that you should hold on to for later. **You'll need it in order to unbind its listeners** using `view.unbind()`.

But what if it is not convenient to hang on to this reference? Must `unbind` *always* be called?

If the view's elements have been removed from the document using a method like jQuery's[`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), will there still be guaranteed memory leaks because Rivets itself will continue to hold a reference to the element or the view?

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation now, still leaking memory, but jQuery remove and such things still causing memory leakage. did you find a solution?

Comment: @AMTourky, for me the question was more of a hypothetical that I wanted to be assured wouldn't happen rather than a problem I was experiencing. As no assurances were forthcoming and everything else indicated I probably shouldn't, I didn't go forward. I could imagine that reporting your issue or making a feature request to the maintainer of rivets could help clarify things (or upvoting the question)...

Comment: I think there still no solution available for this?